# Convert .ppk file to openSSH .pem using Python

Tags: python, pem

I want to grab an AWS instance's .ppk key (doable) and convert it on the fly using Python in .pem openSSH file.

I want to do it automatically without puttyGEN.

I have found this code snippet,
http://www.example-code.com/python/ssh_ppk_to_pem.asp   but I am not sure if it is a good idea to use the -chilkat- library .

Can this conversion be done with the standard Python library or one that can be installed with pip ?

Any code example is welcome but if I am pointed in the right direction I can take it on myself.

Comment: AWS uses .pem files. Only PuTTY uses ppk files. Are you missing the original pem file and trying to recover it by converting a ppk file to pem? Unfortunately, since ppk is only used by PuTTY, I don't know of a good way to do it without puttygen or the chilkat library.

Comment: It looks like Chilkat has done the heavy lifting of implementing the ppk format in Python. If you can't find an open source version and you don't want to pay for Chilkat's implementation, you'll probably have to use the Putty source code to implement your own library.

Comment: @Brian KH : So true! How did I missed that? I use .ppk to SSH with Putty, maybe that's why I got confused. So, let me clarify, I want to take the private key .pem file from AWS and use it with Fabric. Can I use it unchanged or should I convert it (with python) somehow?

Comment: I've never used Fabric before, but I would recommend trying the .pem file, as that is a much more common format. I've never heard of anything else use .ppk than PuTTY.